# How to disable/enable view toolbar menu/action in Eclipse Plugin Development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have view that extends `ViewPart`. In this view, I want to add toolbar menu.

What I know, we can add toolbar menu by using `ActionContributionItem` or `Action`, and add it to `ToolBarMenu` from  `createPartControl` method in `ViewPart`.

But what I don't know is this: How can we disable/enable the toolbar menu programmatically?

So basically, I want to add *Play*, *Stop*, and *Pause* button to toolbar view. So at first, the *Play* button is on enabled mode, and the others are disabled. When I pressed *Play* button, it is disabled, and others will be enabled.

For more details, what I want to achieve is something like the following image.

In the red circle are disabled button, and in the blue circle are enabled button.

[image: View]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using Actions, have a look at Eclipse commands (they are the replacement for actions and function in a cleaner way): http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd.htm

You will see in the documentation that you can enable and disable a command and all places where it's used will properly update their state automatically.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation link. I have read it, but (perhaps I miss it) I didn't found how disabling/enabling the command programmatically. From this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_handlers.htm), it says how to activate command via IHandleService, but dont say how to enabling/disabling it.

Comment: Implement the `IHandler2` interface with your handler and then you can find your handler and dynamically enable/disable it.

Comment: Okay, how to find my handler programmatically and what should I call to disable/enable the handler?

Comment: Is using `IHandlerService handlerService.deactivateHandler()` good approach? So i make playHandler, stopHandler, and so on. If playHandler is clicked then I will deactivate the playHandler and activate the stopHandler? Does it sound good?

Comment: Actually I found another problem. The details is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385959/what-are-wrong-with-this-code-on-activate-deactivate-ihandleractivation-of-comma)

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach which I found by stumbling upon on google. This approach is using ISourceProvider to provide variable state. So we can provide the state of enablement/disablement of command in that class (that implementing ISourceProvider). Here is the detail link http://eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/1-actions-vs-commands?showall=1

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

1: Implement your actions. ex: PlayAction, StopAction.

```java
Public class StartAction extends Action {

@Override
public void run() {
    //actual code run here
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    //This is the initial value, Check for your respective criteria and return the appropriate value.
    return false;
}

@Override
public String getText() {
    return "Play";
}
}
```

2: Register your view part(Player view part)

```java
Public class Playerview extends ViewPart
    {

 @Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

 //your player UI code here.


    //Listener registration. This is very important for enabling and disabling the tool bar level buttons
     addListenerObject(this);


    //Attach selection changed listener to the object where you want to perform the action based on the selection type. ex; viewer
    viewer.addselectionchanged(new SelectionChangedListener())  



      }
        }

    //selection changed

    private class SelectionChangedListener implements ISelectionChangedListener        {

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        ISelection selection = Viewer.getSelection();
        if (selection != null && selection instanceof StructuredSelection) {
            Object firstElement = ((StructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

            //here you can handle the enable or disable based on your selection. that could be your viewer selection or toolbar.
            if (playaction.isEnabled()) { //once clicked on play, stop  should be enabled.
                stopaction.setEnabled(true); //Do required actions here.
                playaction.setEnabled (false);  //do

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

Hope this would help you.