# What are wrong with this code on Activating/Deactivating IHandlerActivation of Command Eclipse Plugin Development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

So, I have 2 commands, which are identified by `PLAY_COMMAND_ID` and `STOP_COMMAND_ID`. Each of command have each handler, respectively `playHandler` and `stopHandler` (these are extending `AbstractHandler` class).

These commands are contributed to my view's toolbar in Button style. Basically what I want is initially the `PLAY_COMMAND` is active but the `STOP_COMMAND` not. When the `PLAY_COMMAND` is clicked, then it will activate the `STOP_COMMAND` then deactivate itself(`PLAY_COMMAND`). And vice versa when the `STOP_COMMAND` clicked.

So what I do is like this. At first it works (I clicked play-button, then stop-button is activated and play-button disabled. I clicked stop-button, then play-button is active and stop-button is disabled. But when I clicked the play-button again, the play-button is still active when the stop-button is active too). So what's wrong with my code here:

```java
private AbstractHandler playHandler, stopHandler, pauseHandler, stepHandler;
private IHandlerActivation playActivation, stopActivation, pauseActivation, stepActivation;
private void createHandlers(){
  final IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    playHandler = new AbstractHandler() {

      @Override
      public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        handlerService.deactivateHandler(playActivation);
        if(stopActivation == null){
          stopActivation = handlerService.activateHandler(STOP_COMMAND_ID, stopHandler);
        } else {
          handlerService.activateHandler(stopActivation);
        }
        return null;
      }
    };

    stopHandler = new AbstractHandler() {

      @Override
      public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        handlerService.deactivateHandler(stopActivation);
        handlerService.activateHandler(playActivation);
        return null;
      }
    };  
    playActivation = handlerService.activateHandler(PLAY_COMMAND_ID, playHandler);
  }
}
```

The `createHandlers()` method is called at the end of `createPartControl(Composite parent)` method in my View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here what I found. The `IHandlerActivation`, that is returned when calling `activateHandler(IHandlerActivation)` method, when it is deactivated, can't be used again in activating the same handler. So the solution is try calling `handlerService.activateHandler(commandID, playHandler)` instead of calling `handlerService.activateHandler(playActivation)`.